# Paste Data with AutoFill in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below that copies the last column filled and paste it into the next empty, simple column. However I need the pasted column to be incremented (with autofill), in my case, with date. January> February> March and so on. Today it sticks with the fixed data.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

LastCol = rLastCell.Column

ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: If your *January> February> March and so on* was generated with a formula then there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If you merely want the months written out in plain English then the following should do the trick: `=TEXT(DATE(2017,COLUMN(),1),"[$-809]MMMM")` ... or am I missing the point?

Comment: @Jeeped I tried using the formula =Date() but no results

Comment: @Ralph the format I need is month / year (17)

Comment: Use `=date(2017, column(A:A), 1)` to get 1/1/2017 and format the cell as `mmmyy` or any other way you prefer. Fill or copy right to get successive months.

Comment: Maybe this format? `=TEXT(DATE(2017,COLUMN(),1),"[$-809]MMMM / (YYYY)")` For more formatting options read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Comment: @Jeeped That was it..Thanks ever so much

Comment: Thank you everybody